# Session management in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, spring-boot, session-cookies

I have a application in which I use Spring boot. I would like to know how to handle multiple sessions. If more than one user logs into the application than how to manage them.

Comment: Your question is about security ? or session with data  ?  A session is a session. If you create a session, spring will send back to user the session id in a cookie, so that future call will be bind to this session.

Comment: My question pertains to multiple sessions. If one session has and another user logs in simultaneously than how to manage the sessions or what exactly needs to be done